# Can't SELECT columns from MYSQL db using "go-sql-driver"

Tags: mysql, go

I decided to make a little project. It's composed by 3 containers:

- Frontend
- Backend
- Database

From Frontend you can complete a form (name, email) and send it to Backend where it will check if the email is already in the Database, if not store data and then send an email of success.
Well, as mentioned the BE is in Go and I'm using the "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" library. Unfortunately, when I try to check if the email is already in DB, the `QueryRow(..)` method returns always nil, even if the email is stored. Here's the code:

```
package appservices

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"
    appmodel "src/app_model"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

func Is_User_Saved(user appmodel.User) bool {
    dsn := "root:example@tcp(db)/mysql"
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", dsn)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("%v\n", err)
        return false
    }
    defer db.Close()

    searched_email := "'" + user.Email + "'"

    row := db.QueryRow("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?", searched_email)

    var email string
    err = row.Scan(&email)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("%v\n", err)
        return false
    }
    return true

}
```

User is a struct with 2 string fields: name and email. I made a docker network, so in the dsn there's only "db" for address.
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, could you help me figuring it out please?
Thank you in advance!

EDIT with Solution:
I wasted 2 hours trying to understand what was wrong... now I restarted everything and It works.
A classic.
So, restart!

Comment: You would get an error when you try to connect to mysql if the issue was with the connection.

Comment: I tried before without ' , it threw an error :/ Funny thing: I wasted 2 hours trying to understand what was wrong... now I restarted everything and It works. A classic.

Comment: `row := db.QueryRow("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?", user.Email)`

Comment: @Shadow based on documentation when there is no row in result it returns error of kind: `sql.ErrNoRows`  (docs: https://go.dev/doc/database/querying)